# vagrant kubernetes oracle virtual box VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, virtualbox

while running vagrant up command on win machine I am getting the below error:

==> kubemaster: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "29046172-fba4-4516-9e28-64ece907dcb7", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by installing latest virtualbox version.